# Windows 10 - Can't open apps I search for in the start menu

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I had a massive issue where my start menu wouldn't load at all but I fixed that by creating a new user account. The start menu works it's just when I [search for something](http://i.imgur.com/dCPL3yN.png?1) I can't actually click the Chrome icon. Nothing happens. I have to right click > open file location > and open it from there.

Please help

Comment: Try "restarting" your PC. No hybrid startup.

Comment: Doesn't matter just found out I can just **hold shift while pressing shutdown**

Comment: No hybrid startup didnt work

Comment: I couldn't find any solution. The only solutions that worked/partially worked for others are - 1. Reinstalling edge 2. re-indexing 3. Start search service 4. Update windows 5. Kill/restart cortana 6. Sign out / Restart PC then Sign-in again 7. Fresh install :) You may want to view event viewer.

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution that works!

1. Sign in from another user account.
2. Navigate to C:\Users\"CORTANA PROBLEM USER"\AppData\Local\Packages\
3. Delete (or rename) Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy
4. Sign in back and check if it works

The full description is located here: http://www.urtech.ca/2016/08/solved-video-how-to-hard-reset-or-remove-cortana-in-windows-10/

---

**Old Post**

Install Windows "Classic Shell". I've tried everything except re-creating new user profile. The Classic Shell helped.

---

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative I'd also suggest to go through the privacy settings in Windows 10 (Settings>Privacy) and enable all of them. After I re-enabled them this problem has been resolved for me. Apparently one or several of them have something to do with it.

Comment: Consider clarifying on what you mean "enable all of them" for the options, etc. you are referring to.If I go to this location, there are many settings from there so be a little more specific for what exactly resolved the issue for you from the Settings > Privacy screen... where and what to do from there?